# libc++ difference between vector::insert overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, libc++

The `std::vector` [implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/vector) of libc++ has the following overloads of `insert`:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
typename vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::iterator
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::insert(const_iterator __position, const_reference __x)
{
    pointer __p = this->__begin_ + (__position - begin());
    if (this->__end_ < this->__end_cap())
    {
        __RAII_IncreaseAnnotator __annotator(*this);
        if (__p == this->__end_)
        {
            __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(),
                                      _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_), __x);
            ++this->__end_;
        }
        else
        {
            __move_range(__p, this->__end_, __p + 1);
            const_pointer __xr = pointer_traits<const_pointer>::pointer_to(__x);
            if (__p <= __xr && __xr < this->__end_) // [*]
                ++__xr;
            *__p = *__xr;
        }
        __annotator.__done();
    }
    else
    {
        allocator_type& __a = this->__alloc();
        __split_buffer<value_type, allocator_type&> __v(__recommend(size() + 1), __p - this->__begin_, __a);
        __v.push_back(__x);
        __p = __swap_out_circular_buffer(__v, __p);
    }
    return __make_iter(__p);
}
```

... and a similar, taking an rvalue reference:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
typename vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::iterator
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::insert(const_iterator __position, value_type&& __x)
{
    pointer __p = this->__begin_ + (__position - begin());
    if (this->__end_ < this->__end_cap())
    {
        __RAII_IncreaseAnnotator __annotator(*this);
        if (__p == this->__end_)
        {
            __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(),
                                      _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_),
                                      _VSTD::move(__x));
            ++this->__end_;
        }
        else
        {
            __move_range(__p, this->__end_, __p + 1);
            *__p = _VSTD::move(__x);
        }
        __annotator.__done();
    }
    else
    {
        allocator_type& __a = this->__alloc();
        __split_buffer<value_type, allocator_type&> __v(__recommend(size() + 1), __p - this->__begin_, __a);
        __v.push_back(_VSTD::move(__x));
        __p = __swap_out_circular_buffer(__v, __p);
    }
    return __make_iter(__p);
}
```

What is the purpose of the branch marked with `[*]` in the first overload? Is it required by the standard? Why is it absent in the second overload? I couldn't find the equivalent construct in `libstdc++`.

**Edit**: `libstdc++` [solves](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/vector.tcc#L127) the same problem by creating a temporary copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a condition to handle the case where the element you're trying to insert already exists in the `vector`.

To explain this, let's start with defining the variables being used in the function.

- `__p` is a pointer to the position where you want to insert the new element
- `__xr` is a pointer to the address of the element you want to insert

The code path you're asking about is executed when the `vector` has sufficient capacity to insert an additional element (`if (this->__end_ < this->__end_cap())`). Also, the insertion point is not the `end()` iterator (`if (__p == this->__end_)` — the `else` path is executed).

In this case, the implementation first moves everything in the range `[__p, end())` one position further — `__move_range(__p, this->__end_, __p + 1);`

But what if the element you're trying to insert was part of the range that just got moved? If so, you must increment the pointer to the element to be inserted. That is what the following lines do

```
if (__p <= __xr && __xr < this->__end_)
  ++__xr;
```

The rvalue reference overload isn't doing the same checks because the implementation is allowed to assume that any object referred to by an rvalue reference is uniquely referenced, so trying to perform an `insert` with an rvalue reference to an element that already exists in the `vector` is undefined behavior.

From N3337, *§17.6.4.9/1 [res.on.arguments]*

> Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions defined in the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>   — ...
>   — If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument.

Here's the [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1204) and rationale for the above clause.

Comment: Great answer! I was missing the fact that it's possible to insert something already inserted.

Comment: @erenon I remember reading a discussion somewhere that that's only possible by reason of omission. Nothing in the standard tells you you are not allowed to insert an element that's already in the same vector, so implementations are required to support that possibility.

Comment: +1, very nice explanation.  I'm purposefully breaking the rules on commenting this upvote because I wrote the code that is being questioned, and the words in the standard that support the implementation.